# I need to sum N highest players' score of each team

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

So I have a sheet like this

players:

[image: players]

and I need to get the sum of 4 highest scores of each team like this:

[image: 4-sum]

even when there are less than 4 players in a team (sum of 1, 2 or 3 best in these cases then) but without any scripts, I believe it's more than possible

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))), 
 MMULT(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY({9^9-C2:C&A2:A, B2:C}, 
 "select max(Col3) 
  where Col2 !='' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"),,999^99))), " "), 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5")*1, {1;1;1;1})})
```

[image: 0]